# Add bookmark to pinboard by scanning qr code

Tags: pinboard

When I scan a qr code (provided it encodes an URL, of course) I'd love to have it automatically added to Pinboard.

Ways I've thought of which sadly don't work:

- find an Android app which offers this feature. The app I use, PinDroid, doesn't. There are two similar apps in the play store, "Pins" and "Pinner for Pinboard": neither one mentions qr codes.
- Use an IFTTT applet. But no, to my knowledge IFTTT can't scan qr codes.

So, is there something I've not thought of by which I could achieve this?

Comment: Not sure that this is something that can be solved here. Questions on this site should be almost exclusively about the web interface, and a web app can't scan anything, and it's obviously not part of the existing web app. Since you seem to be looking for a tool that would let you do this, I think you'll be better off asking at [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: That said, there are a number of ways with Android you can scan a qr code (such as Google Goggles). If there's an URL encoded you'll be able to use the regular Android "share" intent to add it to Pinboard (assuming you've got a good Pinboard app on your device). It might require you to open the URL in a browser as an interim step. But Android solutions are off-topic here. For that, you need to visit [android.se].